# How to avoid saturing frecuency capping at my instagram application?

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-graph-api

I am using instagram api to search specific hashtag getting top media and recent media but graphic shows 4 different calls, so the the 200 limit per hour are consumed really fast. I know about `ig_hashtag_search` , `top_media` and `recent_media` but what i dont know what is `shadowIGHastag`.
Is there a way to avoid overconsumption of my app?
This is how i use the api

```
function insthashtag()
{
    include "../insta/define.php";
    function makeApiCall($endpoint, $type, $params)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();

        if ('POST' == $type) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        } elseif ('GET' == $type) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint . '?' . http_build_query($params));
        }

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return json_decode($response, true);
    }

    $hashtag = 'sedapal';
    $hashtagId = '17843308429009249';

    $hashtagSearchEndpoint = ENDPOINT_BASE . 'ig_hashtag_search';
    $hashtagSearchParams = array(
        'user_id' => $instagramAccountId,
        'fields' => 'id,name',
        'q' => $hashtag,
        'access_token' => $accessToken
    );
    $hashtagSearch = makeApiCall($hashtagSearchEndpoint, 'GET', $hashtagSearchParams);

    /* To get hashtagID */
    /* echo '<pre>';
print_r($hashtagSearch);
die(); */

    $hashtagDataEndpoint = ENDPOINT_BASE . $hashtagId;
    $hashtagDataParams = array(
        'fields' => 'id,name',
        'access_token' => $accessToken
    );
    $hashtagData = makeApiCall($hashtagDataEndpoint, 'GET', $hashtagDataParams);


    $hashtagTopMediaEndpoint = ENDPOINT_BASE . $hashtagId . '/top_media';
    $hashtagTopMediaParams = array(
        'user_id' => $instagramAccountId,
        'fields' => 'id,caption,children,comments_count,like_count,media_type,media_url,permalink',
        'access_token' => $accessToken
    );
    $hashtagTopMedia = makeApiCall($hashtagTopMediaEndpoint, 'GET', $hashtagTopMediaParams);
    $topPost = $hashtagTopMedia['data'][0];
    $topPost1 = $hashtagTopMedia['data'][1];
    $topPost2 = $hashtagTopMedia['data'][3];

    /* To get recent data
    $hashtagRecentEndpoint = ENDPOINT_BASE . $hashtagId . '/recent_media';
    $hashtagRecentParams = array(
        'user_id' => $instagramAccountId,
        'fields' => 'id,caption,children,comments_count,like_count,media_type,media_url,permalink',
        'access_token' => $accessToken
    );
    $hashtagRecent = makeApiCall($hashtagRecentEndpoint, 'GET', $hashtagRecentParams);
     $recentPost = $hashtagRecent['data'][0];
    $recentPost2 = $hashtagRecent['data'][1]; */
    /* $recentPost3 = $hashtagRecent['data'][2]; */
    
    $return = [$topPost['media_type'], $topPost['media_url'], $topPost1['media_type'], $topPost1['media_url'], $topPost2['media_type'], $topPost2['media_url']];
    $jsondata = json_encode($return, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    return $jsondata;
```

[image: calls]

Comment: Instead of making the same call to the API over and over you could cache the response for a period of time.

Comment: you mean to save into cache from javascript, how could i stop calling api in php?